# conditional statement using dictionary isn't working from python3 to python2.4

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, python-2.4

I wrote s small script to iterate through a dictionary in python3 that works just fine. I was working in a different machine that only had python2.4 installed. I copied the script and ran and now the code is not entering the if-statement within the for loop. I am assuming this is just a version discrepancy.

I had tried to look online to see what some differences could be between versions. Closest I have come to is 'dict.iterkeys()'

```
tests = {'1':'test1','2':'test2'}

answer = input('which test? ')

for test in tests:
    if test == answer:
        print(tests[test])
```

The expected output is for the tests I want to be printed. However, in python version 2.4 it is not entering the if-statement at all. In python3 this script works just fine.

Any insight helps.

Thanks!

Comment: In Python 2.4, what is `test`?  Put in a `print` statement to trace the values you're checking.

Comment: Hi, `test` is the variable that will iterate through the dict. I have put in a print statement to track the values. Both inside the `for` loop and inside the `if` statement. That is how I figured out it is not entering the `if` statement.

Comment: Try using `answer = int(input('which test? '))` on python3

Comment: @Jab Note that dict keys are strings, not ints

Comment: My mistake I fixed in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 replaced the old input statement with the functionality of python 2’s `raw_input`. It used to evaluate the input now it’s passed as a string for safety.

Replace the line: (py3)

```
answer = input('which test? ')
```

With: (py2)

```
answer = raw_input('which test? ')
```

Or:

```
answer = str(input('which test? '))
```

Refer to [PEP3111](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111) for more details.

Comment: Quite the opposite... They should replace it with `str(input(...))` instead.

Comment: Excuse me lol thanks! Edited.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of the difference between the input and raw_input functions. My apologies!